# Trouble with finding a c-string substring in C++

Tags: c++, c-strings

long time lurker, first time poster. I have been working on this problem for the last six hours hours.

Problem:

Implement the following functions. Each function deals with null terminated C-Style strings. You can assume that any char array passed into the functions will contain null terminated data. Place all of the functions in a single file and then create a main() function that tests the functions thoroughly.

Note: You may not use any c-string functions other than strlen().

I am having trouble with the fourth function. 
The desired behavior is: This function returns the index in string s where the substring can first be found. For example if s is "Skyscraper" and substring is "ysc" the function would return 2. It should return -1 if the substring does not appear in the string.

prototype:

`int findSubstring(char *str, char substring[])`

Here's my two starts for function definitions, I'm not really sure if either is going in the right direction, I'm having a lot of trouble keeping the loop iterations in my head, any help would be TREMENDOUSLY appreciated.

```
int findSubstring(char *str, char substring[]){

   int subS = -1, index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
   int length1 = (strlen(str) - 1);
   int length2 = (strlen(substring) - 1);

   if(length1 > length2){
      for(int i = 0; i <= length2; i++){

         for(int j = 0; j <= length1; j++){

            if(*(substring + i) == *(str + j) && *(substring +i) != '\0' ){
               i++;

               if(index1 == 0){
                  index1 = i;
               }
            }

            if( *(substring + i) == '\0'){
               subS = i + 2;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   if (length1 < length2){
      cout << "Invalid, substring exceeds size of string!" << endl;
   }
   return subS;

}



int findSubstring(char *str, char substring[]){
   int index = -1;
   int lengthStr = (strlen(str) - 1);
   int lengthSub = (strlen(substring) - 1);

   if (lengthStr < lengthSub){
      cout << "Invalid input, substring exceeds size of string!" << endl;
   }
   if( lengthSub == 0){
      cout << "";
   }

   if (lengthStr > lengthSub){
      for(int i = 0; i <= lengthSub; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j <= lengthStr; j++){



   }

   return index;
}
```

Comment: And? What happens when you run it? How does it fail, and with what arguments? What happens when you work through it with pencil and paper?

Comment: Now that I look at it, I see that your code is... confused. **Solve a simpler problem first.** Try writing a function that tests whether the substring occurs at the beginning of the given string (and if the substring is longer than the string, don't make a fuss, just return `false`). Once that works perfectly, go back to the bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can  replace my  str.size()  and  subString.size()   by  the size of  each  c-string.


int stringPointerOperation( string  str, string subString )
{
    int  pos=0;
    bool  notFound;
    for(int i = 0;  i <  str.size() ;  i++)
    {
        notFound= false;
        if(str[i] == subString[0])
            {
                pos=i;
                for(int  k  = 0 ;  k  < subString.size() &&  k < str.size() ;  k++,i++)
                {
                    if(subString[k] != str[i] )
                        {
                            notFound=true;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
    }

    if(notFound) 
        return -1;
    else 
        return pos;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong strategy for finding a sub-string in a string. The outer `for` loop needs to iterate over the main string and the inner `for` loop needs to iterate over the sub-string.

Say you are looking for `"de"` in `"abcdef"`. The strategy that I find easier to understand and implement is:

Can I find `"de"` starting from `0` of `"abcdef"`. No, I can't.
Can I find `"de"` starting from `1` of `"abcdef"`. No, I can't.
Can I find `"de"` starting from `2` of `"abcdef"`. No, I can't.
Can I find `"de"` starting from `3` of `"abcdef"`. Yes, I can. Return `3`.

Here's a version that works for me.

```
int findSubstring(char *str, char substring[]){

   int i;
   int j;
   int length1 = strlen(str);
   int length2 = strlen(substring);

   if(length1 < length2){
      std::cout << "Invalid, substring exceeds size of string!" << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }

   for(i = 0; i < length1; i++){

      for(j = 0; j < length2; j++){

         // The index to use access the element of str
         // needs to be offset by i.
         if( str[i+j] != substring[j] )
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      if ( j == length2 )
      {
         return i;
      }
   }

   return -1;
}
```